# Turn off AP (hotspot) through terminal

Tags: networking, command-line, hot-spot

How can I turn off the AP hotspot through the terminal, since when I turn it off in network settings the program crashes.

Also: How do I get networking to start when the computer boots up? It doesn't for whatever reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to toggle the Wifi (AP) function using the `nmcli` command line utility e.g.

```
nmcli r wifi off
```

and

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

However if it is the backend `network-manager` that is crashing, the result may be the same.

Comment: That didn't work either, but I managed to turn it off by going into network connections and deleting it. Now Ubuntu doesn't find the wifi anymore (probably since I told it to forget it before, but I changed the name of it afterwards)

Answer (score 2):

The modified version of accepted answer just updated the device status to disabled / enabled but I found these below commands working for me in Ubuntu 18.04:

Turn on wifi hotspot with default generated password:

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot
```

Note: this command will generate a new password for hotspot each time you run it.

To display the password, use this command:

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot --show-secrets
```

To turn the hotspot off:

```
nmcli radio wwan off
```